# Calling javascript function in html second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code for a simple text based game that i am trying to make but i cannot understand why the first time i call my function with a hyperlink 'link1', it works but when i add another link to my html document using javascript, and try to call another function onclick upon that link, it doesn't work. can somebody explain?

```js
var getupvar = document.getElementById("attack");

getupvar.onclick = attack;

function attack() {
  $('<p> Some text </p>').insertBefore("#placeHolder");

  $('<a href="#" id="defend">link2</a>').insertBefore("#placeHolder");
}

var link2event = document.getElementById("defend");

link2event.onclick = defend;

function defend() {
  alert("working now");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="console">
  <p id="startGameMessage"></p>
  <div id="gameArea">
    <p id="gameMessage">Some Text</p>
    <a href="#" id="attack">link1</a>

    <div id="placeHolder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `id`s must be unique within the document.

Comment: As well as IDs needing to be unique, you're attempting to bind to the `defend` element before it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you link up your attack onclick, the element exists. But because `#defend` does not exist on the dom when you run `var link2event = document.getElementById("defend");`, your `onclick` never gets set.

Instead try:

```
var getupvar = document.getElementById("attack");
getupvar.onclick = attack;

function attack(){ 
    $('<p> Some text </p>').insertBefore("#placeHolder");
    $('<a href="#" id="defend">link2</a>').insertBefore("#placeHolder");
    var link2event = document.getElementById("defend");
    link2event.onclick= defend;
}

function defend(){
    alert("working now");
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fv9mpbm6/

This will get your code working how you wish. If you don't do so, your code cannot work because the two lines added to the attack() function will be executed when you call the .js file in your html document as a script and not as a function. This means that the method getElementById("defend") will not find anything, because when you initialize the page, you cannot find any element with this id, you create it when you click on the link.

But do note that if you click attack more than once, your code will break because there will be more than one defend element.

Comment: thank you. and i am not really planning on doing attack and defend. those were just for examples. i am making something which changes the choices after each choice is made. like its sleep or get up but if you choose one of them, it changes to goto school or goto movie. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

When creating dynamic content, never use ids for handlers!  Use classes instead

```
function attack() {
  $('<a href="#" class="defend">link2</a>').insertBefore("#placeHolder");
}
```

Also, to ensure proper handling for elements that may not exist yet, leverage jquery's on functionality

```
$('body').on('click', '.defend', function() {
  alert("working now")
})
```

Comment: and if they do not go somewhere, use a span with a hand cursor or add preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

it is simple, just put the two lines of code

```
var link2event = document.getElementById("defend");
link2event.onclick= defend;
```

inside the attack() function, at the end,and it works. This is the new attack() function:

```
function attack(){ 
$('<p> Some text </p>').insertBefore("#placeHolder");
$('<a href="#" id="defend">link2</a>').insertBefore("#placeHolder");
var link2event = document.getElementById("defend");
link2event.onclick= defend;}
```

If you don't do so this code cannot works because these two lines will be executed when you call the .js file in your html document as a script and not as a function. This means that the method getElementById("defend") will not find nothing, because when you initialize the page, you cannot find any element with this id, you create it when you click on the link.
I hope that this helps!
Cheers!

Comment: oh god simple logic. i've been going head over heels and it was right in front of me. thank you. it works now.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this, I am not sure is this what you expect


var getupvar = document.getElementById("attack"), i=0;

getupvar.onclick = attack;

function attack() {
  $('<p> Some text </p>').insertBefore("#placeHolder");

  $('<a href="#" id="defend'+i+'">link2</a>').insertBefore("#placeHolder");
   var link2event = document.getElementById("defend"+i);

   link2event.onclick = defend;
   i++;
}

function defend() {
  alert("working now");
}
```